# How to use iphone websocket to send data to server

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, web-applications

Hello Please tell me how to use iphone websocket to send data to server in my webapp.

I have completed the webapp. but when i compile it using phone gap cross domain ajax not working good. so i want to use iphone websocket to send data to server

Please tell me about iphone websocket how can i use these to send data to server

Comment: Are you loading your HTML file(s) in Phonegap from a file:// URL or an http:// URL?

Answer (score 0):

I've used [socket-io](http://socket.io/) before, pretty simple and should do the job.